# Замена NaN во фрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть все тот же [фрейм](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data):

Проблема в невозможности создания предсказания, из-за неверного формата данных/наличия Nan во фрейме.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor as rfr
from scipy import stats
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%matplotlib inline

df_train = pd.read_csv('D:\TITAN\Kaggle\House prices/train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('D:\TITAN\Kaggle\House prices/test.csv')

cols = ['LotArea','OverallQual','YearBuilt','TotalBsmtSF','GrLivArea','FullBath','GarageArea', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces']

train_x = df_train[cols]
test_x = df_test[cols]
train_y = df_train['SalePrice']

train_x.fillna(0)

test_x.fillna(0)

pred_model = rfr()
pred_model.fit(train_x, train_y)

predicted_prices = pred_model.predict(test_x)
```

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

```
test_x = test_x.astype(int)
```

ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Если я правильно понимаю, Nan могут ,быть как текст и не как текст. Как это найти/определить/заменить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию, метод [DataFrame.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) возвращает измененный/заполненный DataFrame, но не изменяет оригинальный DataFrame. Поэтому надо делать либо так:

```
train_x = train_x.fillna(0)
test_x = test_x.fillna(0)
```

либо так:

```
train_x.fillna(0, inplace=True)
test_x.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня бывало такое, что когда я игрался с кодировками, у меня файл мог прочитаться, но в нём были одни NaN, из-за неверной кодировки. Тоесть ошибки кодировки не было, но информации я не получил...

Так что попробуйте изменить кодировку при чтении файла